# MariaDB Cuts of Text when select with UNION

Tags: select, text, mariadb, union

I have a recent MariaDB Server (10.3.23-MariaDB-1:10.3.23+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution) on Ubuntu 20.04 which cuts off text. Simple see the following gist: https://gist.github.com/ThomasChr/ed8c2a8405947a8af0cda039bd2c3f0a

Selecting the text with a simple SELECT returns all ~100586 Bytes. Selecting the same text with a simple select before (or after) with UNION ALL (or only UNION) gives me only 34797.

I couldn't find any mentions in the Webs of this behavior nor could I find any variables on my server which seem to be responsible for that. Any ideads what I'm missng?

Comment: Same behavior on:

Ver 10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~focal for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)

Comment: I've filed a bug here: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22923
Hopefully it's not my own fault and it's really a bug.